# Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I have not any problem in my project without this

> Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from
>   method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionProperties$ConnectionProperty.storeTo

please see below image

[image: Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr']

This is my code:

in manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// / VARIABLES
private TextView textWidget;
private TableLayout tableWidget;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CreateOnClickConnect();
}

private void CreateOnClickConnect() {
    textWidget = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tableWidget = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    Button cmd = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    cmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ConnectToMySQL();
        }
    });
}

private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.234.2:3306/";
        String dbName = "_mydb";
        String userName = "_user";
        String userPass = "1234567";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName,
                    userPass);
            response += "Connected!";
            Log.e("MySQL", response);
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response += "Error:" + ex.getMessage();
            Log.e("MySQL", response);
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
    }
}

public void ConnectToMySQL() {
    new Connect().execute();
   }
}
```

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007, and the `newInstance()` part has never been needed.

Comment: thanks i deney this error and my program worked... .